# Chrome is replacing quote by a number

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, character

Why Chrome is replacing simple quote by exponent "9" in my text ?

See picture :

[image]

On MacOs X, with ubuntu font, Firefox and Safari are showing correct text.

Live example : http://comptarama.be/ ("Qui sommes-nous" block on left side after banner)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce that (albeit I'm using Chrome on Win 8.1, rather than Mac, which may make a difference).

Comment: Thanks for testing. I just tested on Win 7 with VirtualBox and I didn't found the problem on FireFox, Chrome and IE9 :(